# Create a mysql conditional insert?

Tags: mysql

How can I check in table_1 if value_a of column_a (and where value_b of column_b = 'x') already exists in column_a of table_2? If it's not present insert it and create a new row for the missing value_a in table_2?

Update: (What seems to work is this:)

```
INSERT INTO products
(key, category)
SELECT key, category
FROM accounts
WHERE category = 'vegan'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM products
          WHERE accounts.key = products.key);
```

Comment: Cleanup noise and remove php tag as this is about mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you transform the column into a primary key ? You'll just have to handle the duplicate entry error code

EDIT :

The solution here is to use SELECT instead of WHERE (thanks to degr)

```
INSERT INTO tableA(`id`,`column1`)
SELECT 44,'Value of Column1' -- The values you want to insert
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id=40) -- check that there is no matching with the request
AND 1=1 --additional conditions
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE id=44);  --additional conditions
```

Comment: I can't use it as primary key ... because out of the 500000 records there might be records using the same unique_id

Comment: Ok, so then, you can do a 

INSERT INTO tableA(your,columns) VALUES(your,values) WHERE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE columnA=uniqueValue) = 0

This will count the occurences in the table 2 and if there is no occurence, it returns 0.

Comment: I'm struggling. Could you provide a more precise code example? I actually do have another where condition ... I want to do it only for certain records. Please see above.

Comment: `INSERT` with `WHERE`?

Comment: Thanks Adrien. I'm almost there. The additional WHERE category = 'vegan'; is not working yet. I updated above.

Comment: Philipp,
Do you want to insert only if the value set for category is "vegan" ?

Comment: Yes ... I was hoping to be able to do that

Comment: I'm sure. But please see my edit above. This seems to work